# Decompress files larger than memory with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, memory, compression

I'm having issue with compressed files. I need to decompress bz2, xz, zst files and work with the output data. However some of the compressed files are 10GB+, and the output will be at least 50GB.

I only have 16GB of RAM, is there a way to:

1. read those compressed files 1GB at a time
2. using the read 1GB compressed data, decompress it and produce 1GB of data sequentially(store in memory, not to output file. I need to work with decompressed data)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're going to have to create a processing pipeline. You could look into using generators for this purpose. You could also look for incremental decompressors such as this one and wrap a generator around it: https://docs.python.org/3/library/bz2.html#bz2.BZ2Decompressor

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, only zstd support stream decompress, see [Stream Reader API](https://pypi.org/project/zstandard/). bz2 and xz both does not support stream decompress, even if I try to read files by chunk, the cutoff will make that chunk invalid.